# Web hosting at Hostingdude.com - Configuring Zone File Record

Tags: domains, web-hosting, dns, networking

I registered an offsite Domain name 'pprs.org.pk' almost few weeks ago and added it to my account via 'add off-site DNS'.

I followed the 'Add Off-Site DNS' [guide](http://help.secureserver.net/article/4041?prog_id=register_cheap_domain_names_cheap_web_hosting&locale=en) available in 'Help Center' section of Hosting dude.

I updated the nameservers at current registrar of pprs.org.pk with standard DNS

```
mns01.domaincontrol.com
mns02.domaincontrol.com
```

Under Domain Details, Setting tab is empty. In zone file:

Server IP addresses:
    72.167.232.225

and

Name servers:

```
ns73.domaincontrol.com (Informational)
ns73.domaincontrol.com (Informational)
```

[image: Registrar and Zone file records]

In the end, I set up the root folder for the website on the web hosting server registered with my account.  pprs.org.pk is not active and live. What am I missing in the process. Please guide.